# Use shell command in-app android

Tags: java, android, shell, root

Can I run these commands from my app using invoking android shell?

```
SU // Get root
flash_image recovery /sdcard/folder/recovery.img
```

Phone will flash recovery through the app.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

## Android Shell Commanding Inside App

I don't know much about Android shell commands, However you can see a sample shell command firing from inside app.

1. If you are dealing with a non-returning command, You can simply try this

   ```
   // PASS THE COMMAND DIRECTLY, HERE FOR ROOT ACCESS
   Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
   ```
2. If your command returns something

   ```
   try{
       // GET THE PROCESS RUNTIME AND EXECUTE su COMMAND
       Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
       // CREATE A DATA-STREAM TO STORE RECORDED VIDEOS
       DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());
       // WRITE THE VIDEO USING STREAMS
       outputStream.writeBytes("screenrecord --time-limit 10 /sdcard/MyVideo.mp4\n");
       // CLEAR THE STREAM
       outputStream.flush();
       // APPEND EOF
       outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
       outputStream.flush();
       // WAIT A WHILE FOR STABILITY
       su.waitFor();
   }catch(IOException e){
       throw new Exception(e);
   }catch(InterruptedException e){
       throw new Exception(e);
   }
   ```

Hope this solves your issue.